# Linux Router Middlebox Failing to Initialize Internet Connection

Tags: linux, router, routing, subnet, dhcp-server

I'm trying to configure a Linux machine as a "middlebox router" that allows a connecting client machine to use the internet connection of the machine itself. It has two physical ethernet interfaces, let's call them eth0 and eth1. eth0 is the internet connection for the middlebox (connects to a switch) and the internet connection tests as working correctly. The LAN subnet for the internet connection is 192.168.0.0/24 with a gateway of 192.168.1.1. I configured a different subnet for the middlebox, shown below in the config file.

I tried to configure the other ethernet interface eth1 to basically share the internet connection, but I'm getting an error message `Internet Connection Failed to Initialize` and the client does not connect to the internet.

What I tried to do to setup this middlebox is this:

```
 1. Installed isc-dhcp-server
 2. Configured DHCP and a static IP address for the client interface eth1
 3. Enabled IPv4 forwarding on the middlebox

systemctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

 4. iptables rules:

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i etho0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

 5. Set the internet connection interface (eth0) as the default route on the middlebox. IFF it's not already set to eth0, I run these commands to set the new default gateway route to eth0 (and printing the default route table shows the gateway is set to the right interface eth0 and the ip address for eth0, as expected):

GW_IP=`route -n | grep -E "^0.0.0.0 .+UG .+eth0" | awk '{print $2}'`
route del default $OTHER_INTERFACE
route add default gw $GW_IP eth0
```

**/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**

```
interface eth1
static ip_address=192.168.34.1/24

authoritative;
subnet 192.168.34.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.34.10 192.168.34.250;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.34.255;
  option routers 192.168.34.1;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
  option domain-name "local-network";
  option domain-name-servers DNS_SERVER_IP1, DNS_SERVER_IP2;
}
```

**/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server**

```
INTERFACESv4="eth1"
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I was thinking this would allow "client" connections on eth1 to use the same gateway and internet connection as eth0 for the middlebox. Does anyone see what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You do not mention where you are seeing this error message.

Comment: There's a GUI popup on the (Ubuntu) client machine that indicates the internet connection failed to initialize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after tinkering and setting back up from scratch again. I had 3 problems with my initial configurations that prevented the middlebox from working:

1. the middlebox needed to set FORWARDING ACCEPT on the client interface, not just enable ipv4 packet forwarding in the kernel
2. the subnet setup by DHCP on the middlebox did not match the subnet on the client machine; the middlebox interface connected to the client and the client interface both need to be on the same subnet
3. the client machine also needs a default gateway route set pointing to the subnet IP address of the middlebox interface connected to the client machine

NOTE: middlebox has two ethernet interfaces (eth0 connecting to the router/main LAN network and eth1 connecting to the client), and the client has one ethernet interface eth0. Further, the primary LAN network is 192.168.1.0/24 and the "middlebox LAN" subnet I changed to 192.168.0.0/24.

**modified /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf on middlebox**

```
interface eth1
static ip_address=192.168.0.1

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.250;
}
option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
option routers 192.168.1.1;   # gateway for internet connecting interface
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option domain-name "local-network";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1. # use router/gateway for DNS
```

Assuming the middlebox itself is successfully connected to a primary LAN and has internet access and DNS working over ethernet interface eth0 ...

**Steps to setup middlebox**

```
ifconfig eth1 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
# Confirm the gateway is 192.168.1.1, or add it on dev eth1 if not
# Configure DNAT on middlebox:
## IPv4 forwarding
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
## masquerade between interfaces going out on eth0 so incoming routes back
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
## enable forwarding from the client interface eth1
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

**Steps to setup client**

```
ifconfig eth0 down
# same subnet but different ip address on middlebox DHCP LAN
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
# set default gateway route to the ip address of the connected middlebox interface
route del -net default
route add default gw 192.168.0.1
# client DNS configuration (multiple options, I chose router DNS)
echo "nameserver 192.168.1.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

**Testing Steps**

Check subnet/address communication works:

1. (from middlebox) $ ping 192.168.0.2
2. (from client)    $ ping 192.168.0.1
3. (from client)    $ ping 8.8.8.8

Check DNS resolution works:

1. (from client)    $ ping google.com OR dig google.com